# How does Ember.js listen to events fired off from the server?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, passport.js

I am using node on the server side and incorporated passport twitter authentication on the server side. My question is:
How do I signal the client when the twitter callback responded?

I have two api endpoints, one is the initial the twitter authentication, the second is for the callback.

```
app.get '/twitter', *calling twitter ...*

app.get '/twitter/callback', *callback from twitter ...*
```

So how can ember listen to the callback event from the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ember can listen to the callback event. However, within your callback you can update a value in an ember object.

For example, here's some code of an ember controller, and a callback

**Ember controller**

```
App.MyController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  authenticated: false,
  updateAuthStatus: function() {
    Em.debug("We're auth status updated and is now: " + this.get('authenticated');
  }.observes('authenticated')
});
```

**Callback**

```
function(authenticated) {
  if (!authenticated) {
    alert("Authentication failed")
  } else {
    App.__container__.lookup("controller:my").set('authenticated', true);
  }
}
```

Better yet, have your passport authentication run from within an ember controller then you won't have to find the controller using the lookup function (and will probably also be a cleaner design).

Comment: Interesting approach, my question will be how do I run twitter passport authentication on ember client? And at which point does the server grant the access token back to the client?

Comment: I'm assuming you're building an ember app, and so most things will happen in ember. Perhaps update your question with some code as to how you think it should work. That'll give a good frame of reference as to where you're coming from.

Comment: update your question with the code. The comment block is too short to be able to paste your code in. Also, indent it by 4 blocks so it appears as a code block. That way its much easier to read

Comment: Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/octapus/5768744

Even most of the stuff is happening on the ember client side, I like to authenticate on the server side and then grant an access code to the client to use in the subsequent calls. 

My question is how do I notify the ember client when the twitter callback? Would it be wise to grant an authorization code during the response from the first twitter call, and exchange for an access code during the twitter callback?

Comment: I wouldn't use express side by side with ember. If you're building an ember app, let ember do all the routing. I don't have much experience working with express, so I'm happy for others to give you better advice.

Comment: Can someone expand on what Gevious is talking about? I understand I can do all my client side routing without the server, but how do the client get the data from the server without the RESTful endpoints. On top of that, I don't want to authenticate on the client side only. My thoughts is to have the server grant an access token to the client, and the client can use it in the subsequent calls.